# Ruby: how to convert VARIANT DATE to datetime

Tags: ruby, date-conversion

In my project i get from external system date&time in VARIANT DATE type and need to convert it to datetime (i.e. 43347.6625 => 04/09/2018 16:29:59).

Do you know how to do it in ruby? what is the best approach? I did not find any ruby built-in method to do such a conversion...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here a method to do the calculation, the date you give is not correct, it should be what this method is returning, check with https://planetcalc.com/7027/

```
def variant2datetime variant
  # number of days after 1-1-1900 minus 2 days for starting with 0
  # and having a day that didn't exist because 1900 wasn't a leap year
  date = Time.new("1900-01-01") + (variant.to_i - 2) * 24 * 60 * 60
  fraction = variant % 1
  hours   = (fraction - fraction.to_i) * 24
  minutes = (hours - hours.to_i) * 60
  seconds = (minutes - minutes.to_i) * 60
  Time.new(date.year, date.month, date.day, hours.to_i, minutes.to_i, seconds.to_i)
end

variant2datetime 43347.6625 # 2018-09-04 15:53:59 +0200
```

Comment: `Time.new("1900-01-01") + ((43347.6625 - 2.00001) * 86400)` will return the same result.

Comment: Thanks - but there is a small difference between both solutions: peter's solution returns 2018-09-04 15:53:59 +0200, engineersmnky's solution returns 2018-09-04 16:53:59 +0200 and https://planetcalc.com/7027/ returns 04/09/2018 16:29:59. When i calculated it manually my result was the same as peter's one.....